# How to de-serialize a JSON list of dictionaries?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "messages":
    [
        {
            "id":"T000000001",
            "sender":"@richusx",
            "subject":"",
            "message":"Hello world!"
        },
        {
            "id":"E000000001",
            "sender":"me@richusx.me",
            "subject":"Test",
            "message":"Hello world!"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is de-serialize the JSON above (from a file), do stuff to that data and then serialize everything back. Asking here as a last resort, I've looked at various online resources, but everything I've found has been for deserializing a single object.

Comment: `everything I've found has been for deserializing a single object` this is a single object. and inside the single object is a single array, and in the single array are more single objects. Use what you have found, and keep going.